# We can allow Service name which can have hyphens(-)?

Tags: service

I was trying to create Service for one use case.
After doing lots of POC what I understood is we cannot have Hyphen in the service name.

link: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/change-in-service-title-naming-limitations-rejects/m-p/1342838#M55387

I tried to create the service in using the below command:
sc.exe create rahul-kumar [image]binpath= "C:\Windows\System32\Windows\PowerShellv1.0powershell.exe"

I'm able to create the Service with Hyphen.

Can Someone confirm me on this?
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, the service name can have hyphens.

The problem is the incorrect path to the powershell executable:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Windows\PowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

It's not System32\Windows\PowerShell\v1.0, it is **System32*\WindowsPowerShell*\v1.0** (notice the backslash between Windows and PowerShell removed)

You need to delete the service and create a new one with this command (fixed path to powershell):

```
sc.exe create rahul-kumar binpath= "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

Comment: Agree, Could you please do a POC a bit and let me know if we can have a hyphen and space in service name or not. I'm getting Now other error.

Comment: @RahulKumar You can't include spaces in a service name. You can however include spaces in service descriptions or display names. I personally recommend naming the service "RahulKumar", "RahulKumarService" or "RahulKumarSvc".

Comment: Agree, but not only Spaces but hyphen as well right ?? But How come I'm able to create service with name like "rahul-kumar" ??

Comment: @RahulKumar The service name **can** have hyphens, but **can't have spaces**. That's why you can create a service named "rahul-kumar", but not "rahul kumar". Either way, "rahul-kumar" or "RahulKumar" would work fine. Apart from that, only the following characters can't be included in a service name: ' ', '/', '\'. Letters and numbers **can** be used in a service name.